# PyQt5 notification from QWidget

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I want my own notifications from phone on PC, like notify-senf. I do popup widgets, but I can't delete then. When I delete it, there is still empty place. How can I do this?
This code is example.

```
class Notification(QWidget):
    signNotifyClose = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        time = datetime.now()
        currentTime = str(time.hour) + ":" + str(time.minute) + "_"
        self.LOG_TAG = currentTime + self.__class__.__name__ + ": "
        super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint) #убирает заголовок, поверх всех окон (| QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        resolution = QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry(-1)
        screenWidth = resolution.width()
        screenHeight = resolution.height()
        print(self.LOG_TAG + "width: " + str(resolution.width()) + " height: " + str(resolution.height()))
        self.count = 0 # Счетчик уведомлений
        self.timer = 3

        self.vboxMainLayout = QVBoxLayout() # layout contain notifications
        self.move(screenWidth, 0)
        self.setLayout(self.vboxMainLayout)

    def setNotify(self, title, notify):
        count = self.count
        title = QLabel()
        title.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid #000")
        title.setText(title)
        title.setStyleSheet("font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; padding: 0;")

        text = QLabel()
        text.setText(notify)
        text.setStyleSheet("font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal; padding: 0;")

        gridNotify = QGridLayout()
        gridNotify.addWidget(title, 0, 0)
        gridNotify.addWidget(text, 1, 0)

        buttonClose = QPushButton()
        buttonClose.clicked.connect(self.deleteWidgets)
        buttonClose.setIcon(QIcon("res/close1.png"))
        buttonClose.setFlat(False)
        buttonClose.setMaximumWidth(14)
        buttonClose.setMaximumHeight(14)

        gridClose = QGridLayout()
        gridClose.addWidget(buttonClose, 0, 0)

        gridLayoutMain = QGridLayout()
        gridLayoutMain.setColumnStretch(0,1)
        gridLayoutMain.setColumnStretch(0,2)
        gridLayoutMain.setColumnStretch(0,3)
        gridLayoutMain.addLayout(gridClose, 0, 4)
        gridLayoutMain.addLayout(gridNotify, 0, 0)

        self.count += 1

        self.vboxMainLayout.addLayout(gridLayoutMain)
        self.show()
        threading.Timer(2, self.delete, args=(gridLayoutMain,)).start()

    def delete(self, layout):
        for i in reversed(range(layout.count())):
            item = layout.takeAt(i)
            widget = item.widget()
            if widget is not None:
                # widget.deleteLater()
            elif item.layout() is not None:
                print("")
                self.delete(item.layout())
```

notifications

[image]

place after delete

[image]

Comment: Why do not you use close()?

Comment: I add more code. How can I close one notification?

Comment: From what I understand, you want to close the application after 2 seconds and all messages should be deleted. I am right?

Comment: No. It example. Notify should close one by one. All notifications i can close by self.close().

Comment: try with my answer :P

Comment: I will try and answer you. Big thanks for help!!))

Comment: If it works for you do not forget to mark my answer as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify the task it is better to create a Widget for the messages as I show below:

```
class Message(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, title, message, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setLayout(QGridLayout())
        self.titleLabel = QLabel(title, self)
        self.titleLabel.setStyleSheet(
            "font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; padding: 0;")
        self.messageLabel = QLabel(message, self)
        self.messageLabel.setStyleSheet(
            "font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal; padding: 0;")
        self.buttonClose = QPushButton(self)
        self.buttonClose.setIcon(QIcon("res/close1.png"))
        self.buttonClose.setFixedSize(14, 14)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.titleLabel, 0, 0)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.messageLabel, 1, 0)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.buttonClose, 0, 1, 2, 1)
```

When you want to remove the message first you must remove it from the layout with the `removeWidget()` function of the layout and then you must use `deleteLater()` to delete itself and its child widget. when we send a signal we can get the object that emits it through `sender()`, in our case it will be the button, and through this we obtain the parent that is our message widget. Then to update the correct size of the layout we use `adjustSize()`. Even removing the entire widget takes a minimum value so it is advisable to close it if there are no messages.

```
class Notification(QWidget):
    signNotifyClose = pyqtSignal(str)
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        time = datetime.now()
        currentTime = str(time.hour) + ":" + str(time.minute) + "_"
        self.LOG_TAG = currentTime + self.__class__.__name__ + ": "
        super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        resolution = QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry(-1)
        screenWidth = resolution.width()
        screenHeight = resolution.height()
        print(self.LOG_TAG + "width: " + str(resolution.width()) + " height: " + str(resolution.height()))
        self.nMessages = 0
        self.mainLayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.move(screenWidth, 0)

    def setNotify(self, title, message):
        m = Message(title, message, self)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(m)
        m.buttonClose.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)
        self.nMessages += 1
        self.show()

    def onClicked(self):
        self.mainLayout.removeWidget(self.sender().parent())
        self.sender().parent().deleteLater()
        self.nMessages -= 1
        self.adjustSize()
        if self.nMessages == 0:
            self.close()
```

Here is an example of how to use it with the following code:

```
class Example(QWidget):
    counter = 0

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        btn = QPushButton("Send Notify", self)
        self.layout().addWidget(btn)

        self.notification = Notification()
        btn.clicked.connect(self.notify)


    def notify(self):
        self.counter += 1
        self.notification.setNotify("Title{}".format(self.counter),
                                    "message{}".format(self.counter))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Example()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you! Tell me, how to make them visible with an inactive main window?

Comment: How do you want to generate messages?

Comment: From QMainWindow
self.notify = Notification()
self.notify.setNotify(title, message)
and receive this code, that you write to me

Comment: I do not understand you, explain yourself better

Comment: Phone receive notifications to app on PC. MainWindow send it to Notification class. But If main window of this app is inactive, notification is not visible on foreground - I must focus this app for see notify

Comment: I still work out of focus or close the widget Example

Comment: For example: if I open chrome maximazed, that I Will no see popup messages. Only if I do active window with my app.
I am sorry for this stupid questions, but I just started to study recently pyqt and in general programming

Comment: Okay, I understand, let me think and I'll give you an answer later.

Comment: Ok. Big  Thanks))

Comment: It was necessary to activate the following flag in Notification:  `Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint`.  Change `self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)` to `self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)`

Comment: Thank a lot!))) I guessed yet))))  Last moment is resize. All notifications remember position of bigger message...
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGLxJ.png

Comment: I did not understand, explain yourself, please

Comment: In this screeshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGLxJ.png. If previous message large than  others, small messages shift to left