# Pyqt5 Notification from scratch

Tags: python-3.x, oop, pyqt5

I wanted a module programmed on PyQt5 that would make notifications appear on the right side of the screen, so i found a question here:
[PyQt5 notification from QWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46389496/pyqt5-notification-from-qwidget)

and i used this code with only a few changes, but the problem is, it creates a new window and does not show the QWidget on screen.
Here is the code

```
class Message(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, title, message, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setLayout(QGridLayout())
        self.titleLabel = QLabel(title, self)
        self.titleLabel.setStyleSheet(
            "font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; padding: 0;")
        self.messageLabel = QLabel(message, self)
        self.messageLabel.setStyleSheet(
            "font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal; padding: 0;")
        self.buttonClose = QPushButton(self)
        self.buttonClose.setIcon(QIcon("extra/close.png"))
        self.buttonClose.setFixedSize(14, 14)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.titleLabel, 0, 0)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.messageLabel, 1, 0)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.buttonClose, 0, 1, 2, 1)


class Notification(QWidget):
    signNotifyClose = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        resolution = QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry(-1)
        screenWidth = resolution.width()
        screenHeight = resolution.height()
        self.nMessages = 0
        self.mainLayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.move(screenWidth, 0)

    def setNotify(self, title, message):
        m = Message(title, message, self)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(m)
        m.buttonClose.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)
        self.nMessages += 1
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: black;")
        self.show()


    def onClicked(self):
        self.mainLayout.removeWidget(self.sender().parent())
        self.sender().parent().deleteLater()
        self.nMessages -= 1
        self.adjustSize()
        if self.nMessages == 0:
            self.close()
```

and this is the file importing the previous one:

```
from notifierP import *
import sys

class Example(QWidget):
    counter = 0

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        btn = QPushButton("Send Notify", self)
        self.layout().addWidget(btn)

        self.notification = Notification()
        btn.clicked.connect(self.notify)


    def notify(self):
        self.counter += 1
        print(self.counter)
        self.notification.setNotify("Title{}".format(self.counter),
                                    "message{}".format(self.counter))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Example()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

My Question is, why does this happen, and how can i fix it?

How it is on my screen

[image]

This all it shows, nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay the problem here was that the

```
self.move()
```

was moving the widget outside the screen, after i changed its possition to inside the screen it works perfectly.